# Elegant way to repace the (Class-)Type of an Instance in Java bytecode

Tags: java, bytecode, bytecode-manipulation

I've been working for some time on a solution for the following problem. Let's say I have following Java code:

```
public class A {
  public void start() {
    List l = new ArrayList();
    l.add("abc");
    System.out.println( l.get(0) );
  }
}
```

The result of compiling this code is a class file `A.class`, containing Java byte code. I've written a `ClassLoader`, which loads `A.class` and executes `start()`. My intention is replacing in the loaded `A.class` (byte code) `new ArrayList()` with `MyArrayList()`:

```
//Before
List l = new ArrayList();
//After
List l = new MyArrayList();
```

The class `MyArrayList` is defined similarly to: `class MyArrayList extends ArrayList`

Comment: And how does your solution look? What parts of it don't you like / do you think should be improved? Where exactly do you need help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a tool like [ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) to parse the file and to replace the occurrence of any `ArrayList` with `MyArrayList`. This would however require that `MyArrayList` defines constructors with an identical signature to the constructors defined in `ArraysList`.

The next question is when you define the changes. You have the following possibilities:

1. Change the implementation at build time: You could write a build tool plugin that applies your transformations.
2. Change the implementation at run time using a Java agent: The [Attach API](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_attach_api) allows you to change a loaded class even at run time.
3. Change the implementation before a class is loaded for a first time: You could use a custom class loader for loading your altered class. This needs to happen before a class is loaded regularly!

Comment: Since it's `MyArrayList extends ArrayList`, I'd assume they would have the same constructor signatures

Comment: No. A constructor is defined individually for each class. Imagine `class Foo { Foo(String s) { } }`. It does not define constructors equal to those in `Object`.

Comment: I meant in regard to the fact that it would inherit the constructors

Comment: Constructors are never inherited. What happens in you code is that you do not explicitly declare one. This results in the Java compiler creating an implicit default constructor which itself implicitly calls its super class's default constructor. Any call to for example `new ArrayList(10)` would however not be possible anymore since `MyArrayList` does not declare such a constructor explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your Answer. I think, 3. (before a class is loaded for a first time) would be the best time for defining the changes.

Comment: You are welcome. Check out the extensive ASM documentation for finding out how this is done if you do not already know. If your question is answered, consider marking it as resolved by accepting an answer.